# HoloLens2 Application made with unity throws Exception "Could not create a device for ''Hand - Right (XRInputV1)"

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Since I updated my HoloLens2 Unity Project to Unity 2020.3 my deployed HoloLens2-Application (in Unity Editor they never happen) always throws the following Exceptions :

```
Could not create a device for 'Hand - Right (XRInputV1)'
(Exception: System.ArgumentException: Expected control positionAccuracy to be of type 'AxisControl' but is of type 'IntegerControl' instead;)
at UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputControll

Could not create a device for 'Hand - Left (XRInputV1)'
(Exception: System.ArgumentException: Expected control positionAccuracy to be of type 'AxisControl' but is of type 'IntegerControl' instead;)
at UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputControll
```

Does anybody know, how to get rid of those Exceptions?

I am using the MixedRealityToolkit 2.7.3 HoloLens2 default Configuration and noticed this problem at Unity Versions 2020.3.8, 2020.3.22 and 2020.3.26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed the Error-Problem by updating to OpenXR plugin. It fixed basically every problem I had so far within my project. By coincidence I came across the plugin as a tarball file while downloading this [sample-project](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples) from Github.

I´d wish to find a place where I can get all the plugins which can be installed via Microsoft FeatureTool on one place as manual download! Maybe someday it will exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please double check the MRTK Input profile setting. You can easily configure the project in Unity Menu: Mixed Reality > Toolkit > Utilities > Configure Project for MRTK

Then, please check out your XR setting, Since you are using Unity 2020.x, you can use OpenXR plugin, see [Choosing an XR configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/xr-project-setup?tabs=openxr#choosing-an-xr-configuration).

If the issue is still there, this may also be caused by your hand control code. Here is discussion with the same exception as yours, see WikkidEdd's reply in this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10225). In their case, they need to use `IntegerControl` instead of `AxisControl`.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer.
I wanted to use the OpenXR approach and was able to install the basic OpenXR-plugin from Unity Registry but if I select it in the XR Plug-In Management I need the corresponding "Microsoft HoloLens feature group".

Unfortunately I currently have no internet access on my developement computer and until now I was not able to find any manuallydownloadable package for this on the internet.

Can you tell me where I can download the OpenXR HoloLensFeatureGroup?
In terms of the Exception I will wait for the next MRTK Update which should have the issue fixed.